# CSHMTL with angular and interpolation

Tags: angularjs, razor

I'm pretty new in CSHTML. But i would like to ask if it is possible to do following. I have some Sitecore field and in cshtml i am using it like

```
@Html.Sitecore.Field('field')
```

Then i am using something like this in same cshtml but it is angular

```
{{value}}
```

Point is that it may change positioning in sitecore (based on words) so we have something like this {0} that i need to replace with angular value then.

is it possible to do something like following ? :

```
@Html.Sitecore.Field('field').ToString().Replace('{0}',{{value}})
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm afraid it won't be feasible. Your cshtml code is run at server. After that, the html+angular is sent to the client's browser, and the angular is run and your server is absolutely not aware of that.

Comment: Sure but serverside code should be loaded first. And im am able to write down both values. Just need to somehow replace them. And this cshtml function like replace etc look quite client side for me

Comment: Then how can i handle cshtml value to angular and replace it within this? I dont want to use jquery or stg like that to get string and replace it with some hidden value... I have the replacement for {0} in angular controller

Answer (score 0):

Actually it worked in this way :

```
@Html.Raw(@Html.Sitecore().Field("Field").ToString().Replace("{0}", "{{value}}"))
```

I needed to put it into @Html.Raw() and change it to string with ToString()